# Django - add required auto-generated `uuid4` to existing project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm trying to add `internal_code` to a `Django Model` in the existing project.

```
internal_code = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
```

The problem is that when running `migrate`, Django raises `IntegrityError`:

```
DETAIL:  Key (internal_code)=(b24f1ca6-bd90-4c91-87b0-5f246a4057e1) is duplicated.
```

I understand that this problem exists only during `migrate` as it is generated just once.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior without having to do this?:

1. set field to `null=True`
2. migrate
3. add `RunPython` that will populate all the existing objects `internal_code` fields
4. set field to `null=False`

EDIT: This is the final migration file. I want to know if I can avoid writing such migration to get the same result (automatic so not touching `shell`)

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import uuid

def gen_uuid(apps, schema_editor):
    Product = apps.get_model('products', 'Product')
    for product in Product.objects.all():
        product.my_sku = uuid.uuid4()
        product.save(update_fields=['my_sku'])


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('products', '0015_auto_20210827_1252'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='product',
            name='my_sku',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(gen_uuid),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='product',
            name='my_sku',
            field=models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, max_length=128, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: this is happening because you have 2 rows in your database with the same internal code ... delete the duplicates would stop this from happening, or removing the unique constraint

Comment: @JoranBeasley I know, thanks. I'm just asking if there is a better/simpler way to do that than writing custom migrations.

Comment: open your shell ... remove duplicates... and you are done... or are you saying its currently null field, and uuid.uuid4 is returning duplicates? (which probably should not happen)

Comment: did you set `default=uuid.uuid4`, or `default=uuid.uuid4()`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem without () but migrations generate it just once. I need to have unique uuids after the migration. I guess there's no other way than to add AddField, RunPython and AlterField.

Comment: @Milano: can you share the migration file where you introduce this?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've added the migration (working one) at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @milano: I mean can you show the *generated* migration, such that it is clear how Django would do the migration automatically.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That would just do the third one in the `operations`.

Comment: @Milano: I would think that it is a mixture of the first and the third: since we are then adding a field immediately, and do not alter it later.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem as I want to run the gen_uuid, I need first to make the field null=True, then I can run the gen_uuid and then modify the field to be not null and unique. I was just curious if I can avoid writing migrations... but that's probably not possible... maybe Postgres could do that.

Comment: @Milano: postgreSQL has a `uuid_generate_v4` function in its extensions that can be used to populate the new column.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sounds interesting, will take a look at it, thank you Willem.

Comment: Just a side note: Unless your obscurification layer (Django) expects bits a uuid requires a length of 16 bytes if declared as  UUID or 36 bytes if declared as TEXT/Varchar. A `uuid` is a 128bit value generally expressed an 32hex characters (2hex characters per byte).